# How to get the value of the button Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html code:

```
<div ng-controller="tablectrl">

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Functions</th>
        <th>Exam Subject</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default" 
            value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/exammanager/delete/{{ x.id }}" ng-click='<?php echo 'delete("{{ x.id }}")'; ?>'>Delete</button>
        </td>
        <td>{{x.subject_id }}</td>
        <td>{{x.start_date }}</td>
        <td>{{x.end_date }}</td>
        <td>{{x.name }}</td>
        <td>{{x.description }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my script:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('tablectrl', function($scope, $http)
{   
    $http.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/exammanager/0/10").then(function(response) 
    {
        $scope.myData = response.data.exams;                    
    }); 

    $scope.pagescopeclick = function(val)
    {
        $http.get(val).then(function(response) 
        {
            $scope.myData = response.data.exams;                
        });
    }//pagescopeclick

    $scope.delete = function(val)
    {
        alert(val);         
    }
});
```

How can I get the {{x.id}} to evaluate in the html loop and be able to pass the variable to the delete function? When I view the html code in the browser it show the evaluated to the correct id, but when i click the button is alerts {{x.id}}

Comment: Why are you using a php tag inside de button? If you need some value from php, you can assign the value to a variable, like `var baseUrl="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"` and use this value later, and, in `button` tag, only html + javascript + angularjs.

Comment: use this <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click='delete(x.id)'>Delete</button>

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual I have the php code inside the button to print out root url of the web app. I am using codeigniter. The button value when click house the information for the delete url.

Comment: @Akhil thank you x.id worked.